# Android Tablet for Testing Phone Apps

Tags: android, testing

I'm thinking of purchasing an Android tablet for development. But I plan on developing both phone and tablet apps. I know that they technically both run they might just look different because of resolution differences.

My question is can I change the screen dimensions of a tablet to have the same screen size as a phone? Not really so much changing the resolution (so it would still take the whole screen), but more cutting of the edges so that the actual screen dimensions are that of a typical phone.

Comment: @CommonsWare I would agree this is a duplicate. I did look but couldn't find that question. Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I will mark this question to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to purchase a tablet, you can still test your applications using [AVDs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html).

I haven't, however, ever heard of a way to change the screen dimensions of the tablet without actually slicing it through with a chainsaw :) If there are any ways I would be really interested in knowing!

Comment: Thanks :), I am aware of AVD's but I would like to be able to test on actual hardware. No matter how close the emulator mimics the hardware it's never perfect.

Comment: I totally agree, sometimes a functionality doesn't work on the Emulator but works on the real device.

Answer (score 0):

[play.google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor) Here is an app by which you can change the density and other root properties of your phone. All the build properties can be edit by this if you have root permission of the device.